# Can the direction of electric field in a parallel plate capacitor be tangent to the surface of the plates?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, conductors, dielectric

We have two parallel plates connected to a source of emf E, and let's say we introduce a dielectric  of constant K, (assume a dielectric slab for simplicity), and we are free to vary the length  of the dielectric slab inside the plate,however  it fills the gap between the plates.So is it possible that the dielectric slab experiences a force in a direction which is tangent to the surface of plates? This can be only possible due to attraction of the capacitor  which is without the dielectric and is with the parallel  combination with the dielectric one , but this contradicts that the field inside a parallel plate remains perepndicular to the surface, which can also be seen from symmetry.